# How to run playwright java test case on AWS Device Farm

Tags: java, aws-device-farm, playwright-java

I want to run my playwright script written in java on AWS device farm browser.
How can I achieve that in java?

Selenium Example is pretty simpler by passing device farm detail in to Remote Webdriver.

not getting enough supporting document for device farm with playwright.